FRA vs "forward on interest rate"?
Consider a forward on a general underlying security in which the holder pays $K$ and receives $S_T$ at $T$. We can show that the forward price at $t\leq T$ is $$F=S_t/Z(t,T),$$ where $Z(t,T)$ denotes the price of a maturity-$T$ ZCB at $t$. This is because the forward is replicated by a portfolio which is short $K$ ZCBs and long the stock.
Now consider an FRA in which the holder pays $(T-T')K$ and receives $(T-T')L_{T'}[T',T]$ at $T$, where $L_{T'}[T',T]$ is the market's realized interest rate for borrowing/lending from $T'$ to $T$. If an FRA is just a forward on an interest rate, why can't we directly apply the above formula to the FRA --- treating $(T-T')L_t[T',T]$, the market's interest rate at $t$ for borrowing/lending from $T'$ to $T$, as an analogue of $S_t$ --- to obtain a forward price of $$F=\frac{(T-T')L_t[T',T]}{Z(t,T)}?$$
Instead, my book derives the FRA's forward price by constructing a replicating portfolio which is long a maturity-$T'$ ZCB and short $1+K(T-T')$ maturity-$T$ ZCBs to derive a forward price of $$F=\left(\frac{Z(t,T')}{Z(t,T)}-1\right)\frac{1}{T-T'}.$$
Why don't the results agree? Is there something different about FRAs which make them not equivalent to a forward on an interest rate?

The idea of the exercise is to calculate the forward rate from things that are observable.  The ZCBs are observable .  You cannot directly observe $L_t[T’,T]$.  Indeed, that is what you are trying to calculate- the correct price now for the interest rate at a future time.  Does that clarify ?
One further comment : interest rates are fundamentally different from stocks, because a stock is an asset which you can buy and hold.  An interest rate is not an asset that you can buy.  The assets in the interest rate world are the ZCBs, so you need to construct the forward rate from the prices of those.
